# Integrar aplicação nodejs a site php em servidores distintos?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

Como posso integrar uma aplicação de *chat* hospedada em [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) ao meu projeto PHP em outro servidor? A aplicação é simples e não usa banco, a ideia seria que no PHP ao fazer *login* automaticamente em Heroku o usuário entre no *chat*...mostrando uma janela ao estilo "widget" no *site* PHP.

Comment: Claro...tava ansioso que esqueci que podia responder minha própria pergunta :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Editado 12/09/2014

Bom foi uma briga para achar esta resposta por isso compartilho aqui!
Exemplo testado em localhost! Requerimentos vide package.json!

Usei xampp como servidor local, não creio que faça diferença usar wamp!
A página index.php e home.php estão em C:\xampp\htdocs\site ou seja na pasta "site" que esta sendo servida por Apache do xampp.
Já a pasta aonde esta o arquivo app.js (servidor NodeJS) e os módulos "express" e "socket-io" esta na área de trabalho a rodar na porta "3000".

Note que apartir da versão 1.1.0 socket.io.js passa a ser chamado via CDN!
É isso bem simples agora é só incrementar.

[DEMO](http://developer58.tk/demo/node-chat/) demonstração com servidor site (Apache) em Hostinger e servidor NodeJS em Heroku

### Pagina index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <center>
       <form action="home.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="name" size="45" placeholder="Diga seu nome :)">
         <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
       </form>
     </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Pagina home.php

```
<?php
   header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
   if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); 
   $name = $_POST['name'];

   $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

   echo $name;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
  <style>
  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
  body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;background:#9F9F9F; }
  #chat{position:fixed;width:20%;height:100%;top:0px;right:0px;background:#181337;}
  #message_space{position:absolute;width:100%;height:80%;top:3%;right:0px;background:#FF71B8;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}
  form { background: #000; padding: 3px; bottom: 0px;right:0px; width: 100%;position:absolute; }
  form textarea {border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 100%;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto; }
  #messages { list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;word-wrap:break-word; }
  #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
  #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
  #visitas{position:absolute;width:100%;padding:1%;top:0px;right:0px;background:#80FFFF;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

   <div id="chat">
      <center><b><span id="visitas"></span></b></center>
      <div id="message_space">
      <ul id="messages"></ul>
   </div>
   <form action="">
      <textarea id="m" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Seu texto aqui..." ></textarea>
      <input id="name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
   </form>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
  // Aqui declaramos a conexão com o caminho e a porta a ser usada pelo socket.io!!!
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

  // Capturando nome!!
  var name = $('#name').val();

  // Aqui iniciamos contador de usuários!!!
  socket.on('visits', function(visitas){
     document.getElementById('visitas').innerHTML = "Usuários Logados: " + visitas;
  });

  // Iniciamos a função de envio de mensagem com a tecla "enter" !!!
  $(function(){
      $("#m").keypress(function (e) {
           if(e.which == 13) {
                  // se pressionada a tecla "enter" enviamos o conteúdo ao servidor !!!
                  socket.emit('chat message', name + ' disse: ' + $('#m').val());
                  // Aqui limpamos a área de texto !!!
                  $('#m').val('');
                  return false;
           }
     });
  });

  // Aqui declaramos o recebimento das mensagens de volta (call back) !!!
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Pagina app.js (servidor NodeJS)

```
// Declaramos a variavel app e requisitamos o "express"
var app = require('express')();
// Declaramos a variavel e o servidor
var http = require('http').Server(app);
// Declaramos a variavel "io" e instanciamos com o servidor
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//  Declaramos de onde virão requisições e para onde responderemos!
app.get('http:/localhost/site', function(req, res){
// Indicamos a página para resposta!
res.sendfile('home.php');
});

// Criamos uma variavel e atribuimos um valor inicial de zero (PS: valor real!)
var visitas = 0;

// Declaramos conexão!
io.on('connection', function(socket){

// Incrementa o total de visitas no site (total de usuários!).
visitas++;

// Envia o total de visitas para todos os usuários.
io.emit('visits', visitas);

// Exibimos no console a rota da conexão!
console.log(socket.client.conn.remoteAddress);

// Imprime no console que houve uma conexão !!!
console.log('a user connected');

socket.on('disconnect', function(){

   // Quando houver uma desconexão fazemos um decremento do número de usuário!
   visitas--;

   // Atualiza o total de usuários para os demais usuários.
   io.emit('visits', visitas);

   // Imprime no console que houve uma desconexão e quantos usuários estão online!!!
   console.log('user disconnected...rest: ' + visitas + ' users online!');
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
});
});

// Startamos na porta "3000" e exibimos no console!
http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('Start Server on Port: 3000');
});
```

### Arquivo package.json

```
  {
    "name": "Nome do aplicativo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Descrição do que é isso",
    "main": "app.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "socket.io": "~1.1.0",
      "express": "~4.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},

    "author": "Seu Nome",
    "url": "http://seusite.com",
    "email": "seuemail@mail.com",
    "license": "o tipo de licença",
    "bugs": {
      "url": "http://endercoparareportarbugs.com"
    },
    "homepage": "http://suapaginaprincipal.com"
  }
```

Comment: Um tempo atrás também fiz algo similar em um projeto que precisava de chat ao vivo, mas para algo temporário ou que não requer autenticação até pode ser uma boa, mas na perspectiva de segurança precisamos melhorar mais.

A alternativa que cheguei a pesquisar seria utilizar JWT tanto para autenticação com o BackEnd PHP e o Node.js para evitar diversas situações indesejadas com websockets ativos, que variam desde usar seu servidor de websocket (processamento) em outro sistema aleatório até envio de comandos indesejados para seus próprios usuários.